# Count lines with alphabet in linux

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a file with a number of lines in a file `filename`.

I want to count how many lines start with character 'a', with 'b' and so on in one go.

What command i should execute.?

Comment: you want lines like "abced...", or lines beginning with an alphabet letter ? both are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure I understand your question correctly, is this what you are looking for?

```
$ cat foo.input
afoo
abar
bfoo
bbar
bquux
cfoo

$ awk '{a[substr($0, 1, 1)]++}END{for (c in a)print c, a[c]}' foo.input
a 2
b 3
c 1
```

Another, simpler solution is to use `colrm` and `uniq`:

```
$ colrm 2 < foo.input | uniq -c
      2 a
      3 b
      1 c
```

Comment: `colrm` is a _need-to-remember_ command... but I gave you already my `+1` ;)

Comment: @mpy I agree, and to be honest, I think this is the first time I have actually used it usefully since I never remember it ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect job for `uniq`:

```
uniq -c -w 1 filename
```

`-w 1` compares only the the first character of each line; `-c` counts the occurrences.

With `foo.input` from [Adrian's answer](https://superuser.com/a/638651/195224) you get (don't be confused about `afoo`, `bfoo` etc.; these are simply the first lines which start with `a`, `b`, etc.)

```
    2 afoo
    3 bfoo
    1 cfoo
```

Pipe the result through `sort -n`, if you want it sorted by the number of occurrences:

```
$ uniq -c -w 1 foo.input | sort -n
    1 cfoo
    2 afoo
    3 bfoo
```

Comment: Much much simplier than my solution, except it will handle Uppercase separatly.

Comment: I wanted to post this first, but the output is a bit unlucky without further processing.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: You are right, I was confused for a moment myself and therefore added a note in the text. But IMHO it answers the question fine as this command counts correctly.

Comment: I agree, your answer is perfectly valid, so +1 (see my edit for a `uniq` solution that gets rid of the confusing output).

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you're more into use of perl and grep:

```
perl -le '$, = "\n"; print ("a".."z")' | xargs -i grep -c '^{}' foo.input
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, because sometimes it's easier to remember small blocks and assemble them :

```
$ cat foo.input
afoo
abar
bfoo
bbar
bquux
cfoo

$ cat foo.input | cut -c 1 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' | sort | grep '^[a-z]'| uniq -c
      2 a
      3 b
      1 c
```

Explanation of the one-liner :

- `cat` read the file
- `cut -c 1` trims everything but the first character of each line
- `tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'` replaces uppercase to lowercase
- `sort` ... sorts the lines
- `grep '^[a-z]'` remove lines not beginning with a letter
- `uniq -c` counts identical lines

Comment: You could use `cut -c 1 foo.input` instead of `cat foo.input | cut -c 1`...

Comment: Actually I was doing `cut -c 1 <foo.input` but that messed up with the <pre> formatting. Your alternative works indeed.

Comment: You might want to use `[[:upper:]]`/`[[:lower:]]`, just in case.